# Xamarin (Frame.)GestureRecognizers doesn't work

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying to make a TapGestureRecognizer on some frames, but when I test it, nothing happens.

**xaml**

```
<StackLayout>
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="380" TranslationX="12.5" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="120">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Sport_Clicked"/>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="-10">
                <Label Text="Sport" FontSize="17"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>

    <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="380" TranslationX="187.5" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="120">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Voeding_Clicked"/>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="-10">
                <Label Text="Voeding" FontSize="17"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>

    <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="495" TranslationX="12.5" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="120">
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Slaap_Clicked"/>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="-10">
                <Label Text="Slaap" FontSize="17" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</AbsoluteLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**cs**

```
void Sport_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new NavigationPage(new SportPage());
}

void Voeding_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new NavigationPage(new VoedingPage());
}

void Slaap_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new NavigationPage(new SlaapPage());
}
```

I am not getting any warnings or errors when testing. Is there something that overlaps the frames which you cannot see that causes to blocks the input?

**Edit:**

This is how a frame looks with the following code

```
<Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TranslationY="380" TranslationX="187.5" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="120" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Green">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Voeding_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="-10" BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Label Text="Voeding" FontSize="17"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

[image]

With this code I should be able to click the green part and get a response, but I'm not getting that? Is there a way to have something that will overlap the whole frame so I can use that to click on?

Comment: The contents of the frame would overlap it of course, either move it the StackLayout or add it to the stacklayout and keep both (if you have large margins/paddings that would improve the total touch area....)

Comment: Like this? https://pastebin.com/04SU59HG. This also didn't work.

Comment: If you have the Xamarin Inspector (enterprise license) you can see if something is overlapping and blocking touch input https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/inspector/ Otherwise you can assign different background colors to the controls and do it that way....

Comment: Please see the edited post. I have no Xamarin Inspector.

Comment: Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

Your `Frame` doesn't respond to your `TapGestureRecognizer` is caused by your `TranslationY="380" TranslationX="187.5"` properies. You cannot tap on the control that is out of bounds of parent view, even if this control is seen.

> Translating an element outside the bounds of its parent container may
>   prevent inputs from working.

**Solution:**

Remove the `TranslationY` and `TranslationX` properties and layout your `Frame` in other ways.

**Edited:**

You can see the screenshort below, I write a simple demo and add `PaleGreen` as `AbsoluteLayout`'s backgroundColor. Your `Frame` is out of bounds of parent view.So it will not do response to `TapGestureRecognizer`.

So, set `FillAndExpand` to `AbsoluteLayout's` `VerticalOptions` property to make sure your Frame is inside the bounds of parent view.

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="PaleGreen" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

I updated a screenshot here,hope you can understand well:

[image: subViewOutOfParentView]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I now go the Frame at the right position using `Margin`, but I don't know how to place the GestureRecognizer so that it overlaps the whole frame. How should I do that, because at the moment I still doesn't respond.

Comment: @JipHarthoorn See my edit, reply me if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks. I am now using this code https://pastebin.com/JXfPsukB I added `FillAndExpand` and palegreen color and this is the result https://i.gyazo.com/2c423f46d4b3ef1ecadc966020b95e42.jpg. However, still nothing happens when I click anything.

Comment: I just copy your code and add a breakpoint in `Sport_Clicked`. It really entry the function and works well. Is there any other code?

Comment: Weird... this is my full code https://pastebin.com/adxGdEzG, maybe you could have a look at it

Comment: I tested again and it really worked. Can you please create a new project and add your codes of `Frame` to test again? And add a `breakpoint` to the tap function in code benhind.

Comment: Thanks to the `breakpoint` I found out that there was something wrong in my function. It works now. Thanks a lot!